# htaccess partial query string rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

REAL URL: example.com/projects/test/?action=Something&var=val

FAKE(SEO) URL: example.com/test/Something/?var=val

I am looking to re write the following Original URL to the Desired URL. I have

`RewriteRule ^test/?([^/]*)/?$ /projects/test/?action=$1&var=$2 [L]`

However, the problem is that I want the action to always look like a folder and allow for different actions to have different parameters. I don't need the parameters to look neat though so it is enough to have a query string at the end of the url.

edit: clarified URLs

Comment: Which is the _real_ URI (the directory etc. which really physically exists) and which is the [SEO] one coming in from the outside world? Your sample rewrite makes it look like the "Original" URI is the real one. Is the "Desired" URI the one coming in to your server? If you want to simply preserve the incoming Query String, add the [QSA] flag to the rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the flag [QSA] solved the problem.